# Line break after header of theorem environment followed by multicols body causes header-body overlap

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, multicol, amsthm, ntheorem

I use TeXLive 2011.

I use [ntheorem](/questions/tagged/ntheorem) and [multicol](/questions/tagged/multicol).
In a theorem environment, I want the theorem header to be separated from the body by a line break such that the `multicols`-environment get's that and starts its second column at the same height as the first in the body.

This is roughly where the problem came from – in combination with a list from [enumitem](/questions/tagged/enumitem):

[image: version 1 – using indentbreak]
[image: version 2 – using break]

However – while writing the question, I noticed it can be cut down to the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{
        ntheorem,
        multicol,
    }

\usepakage{lipsum}

\makeatletter  
    \newtheoremstyle{indentbreak}
        {\item[##1]}
        {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{##3}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{indentbreak}
%\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{indentbreaktheorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{indentbreaktheorem}[Talking a lot and a lot and a lot and lot and a lot and a lot and a lot.]
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \lipsum*[1]
        \end{multicols}{2}
    \end{indentbreaktheorem}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this using the self-defined indentbreak environment:

[image: version 1 – using indentbreak]

The break environment yields a similar result (as above with the listings).

How can I define a theorem style such that this issue is resolved?
I want to stay with [ntheorem](/questions/tagged/ntheorem), but I am also interested in solutions for [amsthm](/questions/tagged/amsthm).

Answer (score 3):

you don't really need anything that complicated.  using the default theorem style of `amsthm`, all you need to do to break it to a new line is put

```
\leavevmode
```

right after the optional text, as

```
\begin{theorem}[optional text]\leavevmode
```

downsides:

- the optional text will be lightface roman, not bold (as it is formatted with `ntheorem`),
- if the optional text is *very* long, it won't automatically split to a second line (but that's also a problem with `ntheorem`).

both of these (mis)features are on the list to be reconsidered with the next overhaul of `amsthm`, but that hasn't been scheduled yet.

Comment: I have also set up an environment with `ntheorem` to allow a  text indentation while the header is not indented. Also I want the optional text to replace the default displayed theorem name. I couldn't do this with `amsthm`. I thought a solution to the problem with `amsthm` might contribute to a solution with `ntheorem`. So this doesn't help me much. Many thanks anyway.